# problems with usernames in docker

Tags: docker, redhat-enterprise-linux, root, daemon

Good afternoon, I am currently configuring the user name for my containers in the daemon.json file and following the tutorials that I post below:

I am using the following documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/

https://sandro-keil.de/blog/docker-daemon-tuning-and-json-file-configuration/

```
[dockermd]# sudo systemctl restart docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running systemctl status docker.service

```
[dockermd]# sudo systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─http-proxy.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-08-05 14:09:34 -04; 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 2480121 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2480121 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 05 14:09:34 TMT097 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=2s expired, scheduling restart.
Aug 05 14:09:34 TMT097 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Aug 05 14:09:34 TMT097 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 05 14:09:34 TMT097 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 05 14:09:34 TMT097 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 05 14:09:34 TMT097 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Running dockerd

```
dockerd unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: open /etc/docker/daemon.json: permission denied
```

so I have my daemon.json

```
  {
    
            "data-root": "/opt/docker",
            "storage-driver": "overlay2",
            "log-driver": "json-file",
            "userns-remap": "10007:10007",
            "log-opts": {
         

           "max-size": "10m",
                "max-file": "3"
  }
}
```

[image]

my id user

[image]

I need to do this, because for security reasons, the use of root permissions is very limited, so many functionalities of docker root permissions, and I am doing this test with a view to having the least use of root in production

What solution could I apply?

Comment: What user id runs `dockerd`, and what are the flags on `/etc/docker/daemon.json`?

Comment: Can i change the user id to execute dockerd? How is it done?

Comment: As the user who is running dockerd?

Comment: You possibly could run `dockerd` with a user id other than root, but you would have to grand it near-root privileges. so security-wise, there would be very little gain. Consider also that non-experts using non-standard setups are more likely to create vulnerabilities than to close existing ones.

Comment: When it refers to privileges close to root, you mean that there are levels to grant sudo permissions, what would those levels be?

Comment: Switching to another userid, for a start...

Comment: How can I change the user ID?